# While AR integrating in custom APP getting errors :(

Tags: iphone, objective-c, augmented-reality

ld: warning: in /Users/kunwarhanda/Documents/Augmented/WikitudeAPI/libWikitudeAPI.a, missing required architecture i386 in file
Undefined symbols:

"_OBJC_CLASS_$_WTPoi", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref-to-WTPoi in AugmentedAppDelegate.o
      objc-class-ref-to-WTPoi in CustomMenuButtonDelegateImpl1.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_WikitudeARCustomMenuButton", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref-to-WikitudeARCustomMenuButton in AugmentedAppDelegate.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_WikitudeARView
Controller", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref-to-WikitudeARViewController in AugmentedAppDelegate.o
      objc-class-ref-to-WikitudeARViewController in CustomMenuButtonDelegateImpl1.o
      objc-class-ref-to-WikitudeARViewController in CustomMenuButtonDelegateImpl3.o
ld: symbol(s) not found
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

**I have cross checked that libWikitudeAPI.a is imported still does'nt know about this error and by the way m new to iPhone

Please can some one help me in this Thanks in advance **

Comment: You are running in the simulator right? Have you tried running in the phone directly?

Comment: yes i am running on simulator , and no i havnt tried it on phone does it matter?

Comment: its installing on phone nw bt freezes on start ,il look into it but can u tell me wat was the problem for my future reference.

Comment: As Rahul said, the error seemed to indicate the library did not support architecture i386, which would be your Mac architecture, while iPhone is arm6/7.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the library is only for device not for simulator. Try debug your app and use NSZombieEnabled environment variable for finding actual crash reasons.